# Erlang process messaging receiving

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang

I am training in parallel calculations with Erlang. I have following code, that calculates pi number:

```
start(To)->
    Self = self(),
    Cores = erlang:system_info(schedulers_online),
    {Step, Delta} = {1/To, round(To / Cores)},
    Pids = lists:map(fun (El) ->
        spawn(fun()->
            Self ! {sum, calculate(from(El, Delta), to(El, Delta), Step)}
        end)
    end, lists:seq(1, Cores)),
    lists:sum([receive {sum, S} -> S end || _ <- Pids ]) * Step.
```

Now, it goes magic to me

```
lists:sum([receive {sum, S} -> S end || _ <- Pids ])
```

Please, explain how this magic works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lists:sum([receive {sum, S} -> S end || _ <- Pids ])
```

lets go part by part, first the function [sum](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sum-1), which just sum all the elements from a list, i.e.:

```
1> lists:sum([1, 2, 3]).
6
```

`lists:sum(SomeList) * Step.` will just do a multiplication between the sum of the element of *SomeList* and the value in *Step*.

The interesting part is how the list is built, which is built by the code:

```
[receive {sum, S} -> S end || _ <- Pids ]
```

What you have there is a [List Comprehension](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html). `Pids` is an Erlang list which has the Process ID (PID) of each one of the process you created to process the pi number on:

```
Pids = lists:map(fun (El) ->
    spawn(fun()->
        Self ! {sum, calculate(from(El, Delta), to(El, Delta), Step)}
    end)
end, lists:seq(1, Cores)).
```

So imagine you have 4 Cores, that function will create 4 process, probably with a list like `[<0.36.0>, <0.38.0>, <0.40.0>, <0.42.0>]`, the main important idea, is that if you have 4 cores, you will be creating 4 processese, if you have 8 cores, 8 processes, and so on.

Each one of the processes, will call the function `calculate` and will send the result to `Self` as a message, which you can see here:

```
Self ! {sum, calculate(from(El, Delta), to(El, Delta), Step)}
```

So if you have 4 elements, you can try doing something like:

```
6> [X || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4]].
[1,2,3,4]
```

And there, you are building a list Compression with each element of the list. Now, lets say you don't care about the Elements of the list you are using to build your new list, you can do something like:

```
7> [1 || _ <- [1, 2, 3, 4]].
[1,1,1,1]
```

And you will be using the list compression as a for bucle, you don't really care about the elements of the list you are using to build your new list, which is exactly this case, where you are doing something like:

```
[1 || _ <- Pids ]
```

You don't really care what is the content of `Pids`, you are interested in the amount of elements the list `Pids` has.

So if the list Pids has 4 elements, you will be executing the receive function four times:

```
receive 
    {sum, S} -> 
        S 
end
```

That receive function, will listen for any Message sent to the process, with the pattern `{sum, S}` which is the same patter you are sending with `{sum, calculate(from(El, Delta), to(El, Delta), Step)}`. The return value of the function would be `S`, which in that case, will be the result of `calculate(from(El, Delta), to(El, Delta), Step)`.

At the end, you will have a list with 4 elements (again, assuming you have 4 cores) with the result calculated by the four processes you started.